# ModelMetadataProvider overrides alternative to MetadataTypeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, reflection

After playing around with Asp.Net MVC for some time I have decided to actually use it in a project. One of the issues that came up is that the frontend site might have different validation rules for a given model than the admin panel.

I am aware of the MetadataType property but since you have more than one contexts this would not work for us out of the box.

In order to solve this I implemented a custom ModelMetadataProvider that redirects the default ModelMetdataProvider to a different type based on the request's execution context. This works pretty well for displaying the needed UI.

The part of this solution I do not like is that I ended up reading the stack from my custom model metadata provider to determine if the given call is for model binding. This is because when I did not do that I would correctly get "Object does not match target type" during the call to TryUpdateModel from the Controller since the model binder was trying to use properties from type A to set values to an instance of type B.

Is reading the call stack such a bad idea for production? 
Is there a way to replicate the MetadataTypeAttribute behavior selectively without using attributes?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those instances where you wish the ASP.NET MVC Team hadn't sealed a class - I'm sure they had their reasons. I was going to suggest simply creating your own attribute, derived from MetadataTypeAttribute.

One way to go about this is to take the source of the attribute and write your own:

http://dotnetinside.com/framework/v4.0.30319/framework/v4.0.30319/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/MetadataTypeAttribute

Although, of course, this makes your code less maintainable.

I would assert that to the best of my knowledge, you are already making the right decision with a ModelMetadataProvider as your solution. I'm a little nervous for you regarding analysing the call stack though, change locations, move something to an area; you get my drift, i.e. it would be very easy to break the code with a build time decision that isn't found until runtime or beyond QA.

You haven't supplied how the context is roughly determined, but I would personally tackle that by adding a property to the class itself with an Enum (finite possibilities and design time breakage) with a list of possible contexts, then during spin up of the class, populate it, ready for execution of the Provider, which will pass through the correct metatdatatype based on the value of the Enum.

Many ways to skin this cat, but something that is going to break on build will serve you best, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using MVC 6 you may find [ModelMetadata Fluent Configuration](https://github.com/MvcExtensions/Core/wiki/ModelMetadata-Fluent-Configuration) useful.

Some nice examples of how to use it can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/introducing-fluent-metadataprovider-for-asp-net-mvc) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/more-on-fluent-metadataprovider-for-asp-net-mvc).

What is really important is that it is just code which is completely under your control. Thus, once you have different contexts, you may decide to define *different configurations*, or you may play a bit harder and make (a set of) *different registrations* for different contexts.

What really helps is "decorating" (the term used on purpose!) properties of a base class, at least nothing seems to stooping you from doing it.

**EDIT:** Model Metadata **shouldn't** be confused with [WCF RIA Services Contrib](http://riaservicescontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FluentMetadata%20for%20WCF%20RIA%20Services).